# Is there a way to trace and inherit data access rule after query

Tags: sql, business-intelligence, data-access

My company has a BI product that basically provide GUI solution for DIY SQL queries without coding.

Now we have this huge customer, which has a data access management system with rules according to roles and teams already in place. We simply integrated their system to our tool and thought the job was done.

However, one of their demands was that they need data access management not only on data sources, but also on results; and they need it done automatically. They explained that when management share queries to teams, it's required that personnels in different department only saw data correspondingly. And they can't have managers understand how to manually set up access rules.

```
Say you select something from table A & table B:

Select A.FieldA as FA, B.FieldB as FB, X=A.FieldA+B.FieldB
       from A join B group by Z where X > 100

Of the query result:
       FA inherit A.FieldA's data access rules;
       FB inheirt B.FieldB's;
       X inherit the join set of both.
```

What makes things more complex is that results from one query could be used as data sources in future queries.

We've done nothing similar before, and it's not cheap to start from scratch either.
Do anyone know any ready implementations, or simpler solutions to this problem?